# How to show Observables in components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I have the following code in a component:

```
ngOnInit(): void
    {
        const source = this.categoryService.getCategories();
        const sourceedit = source.subscribe(aff => console.log(aff));
        const example = source.map((categor) => categor.map((categories) => {
        const links = this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(categories.id)
                    .subscribe(valeur => console.log(valeur));
            return categories.id
        }));
        const categories = example.subscribe(val => console.log("valeur: "+val));
     }
```

with the following result in the console:
[image]

In my .ts template file, I have the following:

```
<tr *ngFor="let category of categories | async; let id = index">
        <td>
            <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-data-table__select" for="row[3]">
            <input type="checkbox" id="row[3]" class="mdl-checkbox__input"/>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><a [routerLink]="['/category/links']"></a>{{category.categoryName }}
        </td>
        <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{category.categoryName}}
        </td>
        <td #category.id><i (click)="deleteCategory(id)" class="material-icons">delete</i>
        </td>
</tr>
```

and nothing is shown.
I want to show categories in the table and the result of the count too.

Thanks in advance and Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the provided code it doesn't look like you are setting `this.categories` equal to the response from the server/service within your `subscribe()` statements.

You'd need to do something like the following to ensure your `*ngFor="let category of categories` can display the categories collection data, assuming the method `getCategories()` returns an `Observable<Category[]>` or similar observable collection that is mapped to JSON:

Service:

```
getCategories(): Observable<Category[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.categoriesUrl)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json() as Category[])
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Component:

```
this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(categories => this.categories = categories);
```

The same goes for count. You need to make sure you are setting a class variable or similar equal to the count for each category.

TS:

```
getCount(categoryId: number): {
    this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(categories.id).subscribe(valeur => this.categories[categories.id].valeur = valeur);
}
```

HTML:

```
<td>Count: {{getCount(category.id)}}</td>
```

Comment: Hello, for categories writting ''this.categories = this.categoryService.getCategories();'' is enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the **solution** to the problem:

```
ngOnInit(): void
{
    this.categories = this.categoryService.getCategories();
    const example = this.categories
        .mergeMap((categor) => categor
            .map((myCateg) => {
        this.categoryService.countCategoryLinks(myCateg.id)
            .map(numlinks => {
                myCateg.numlinks = numlinks.count;
                return myCateg;
            })
                //Object.assign(myCateg,{numLinks: numlinks}))
            .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
        return myCateg
    }));

            example.subscribe(val => console.log("value2: "+val));

}
```